# Quartz C# scheduler to run every 5 minutes at 2 seconds, every N minutes at X seconds

Tags: c#, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I want to schedule a job every N minutes at X seconds, that is every 5(can be 1,3,5,10,15...n) minutes this is straight **WithIntervalInMinutes(1)**. But I need addition to this trigger should be executed ad 2nd second of that trigger minute.
For example Trigger starts now or at specified time lets say at 9:15 AM, with interval 5 minutes 2 seconds, then it should trigger
9:20:02, 9:25:02, 9:30:02 (02 is seconds of that minute)

so far i tried, fully working example

```
public class MyJobScheduler : IMyJobScheduler
{
private readonly IScheduler _scheduler;

public MyJobScheduler(IScheduler scheduler)
{
    _scheduler = scheduler;
}

public void Start()
{

    _scheduler.Start();


    ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
        .WithIdentity("ScrapGoldRateTrigger1", "group123").StartNow()
        .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
                .RepeatForever()
                .WithIntervalInSeconds(2)
        )
        .Build();


    ITrigger trigger2_every5min_at_2_seconds = TriggerBuilder.Create()
        .WithIdentity("ScrapGoldRateTrigger2", "group123").StartNow()
        .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
                .RepeatForever()
                .WithIntervalInMinutes(5) // it can be any minute frequency
                .WithIntervalInSeconds(2)
                )
        .Build();

    IJobDetail job1 = JobBuilder.Create<ScrapperCandlesHistoryJob>()
        .WithIdentity("ScrapGoldRate", "group123")
        .Build();

    var listOfJobs =
        new Dictionary<IJobDetail, IReadOnlyCollection<ITrigger>>() { { job1, new ITrigger[2] { trigger, trigger2_every5min_at_2_seconds } } };


    _scheduler.ScheduleJobs(listOfJobs, replace: true, default);
}
```

**trigger2_every5min_at_2_seconds** this trigger is not working as expected.
this should execute every 5 minutes at 2 seconds. or if configured every 3 minutes at 6 seconds means if trigger start time at 9:15, then 9:18:06, 9:21:06 and so on it should execute.
Python i'm able to with this trigger
Trigger([
CronTrigger(day_of_week='*', hour='9', minute='35', second='2', timezone="Asia/Kolkata")]

cron expression seems not support seconds level "*/5 * * * *"

Job class

```
public class ScrapperCandlesHistoryJob : IJob
 {
private ILogger logger;

public ScrapperCandlesHistoryJob()
{
    this.logger = LogManager.GetLogger("default");
}

async Task IJob.Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
{
    logger.Info($"@ {DateTime.Now} job {context.JobDetail.Key.Name} is executing...");
    logger.Info("Trigger {0} in group {1} was fired", context.Trigger.Key.Name, context.Trigger.Key.Group);
}
 }
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try 2 0/5 * 1/1 * ? *

Comment: If that doesn't suit, try a SimpleSchedule with 5 minute intervals, but rather than using StartNow, use StartAt and calculate the time you want it to start including the seconds.

Comment: it (2 0/5 * 1/1 * ? *) seems they may work based on some cron expression generators sites [link](http://www.cronmaker.com/;jsessionid=node043fvg0znhr4kliktjfwrm5zk411545.node0?0), but not tested. But many other cron expression generators says it is not standard CRON expression. This  standard format * * * * *  has **No Seconds expression**, only (minute (0-59) hour (0 - 23) day of the month (1 - 31) month (1 - 12) day of the week (0 - 6)). But you answer has 7 length. How your answer can be valid. [link] (https://crontab.guru/#2_0/5_*_1/1_*_?_*) says invalid expression.

Comment: It is confusing, but Quartz cron expressions are not the same as linux cron expressions and has some extra features (like seconds or L for Last day of the week/month) etc.  See https://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.3.0/tutorials/crontrigger.html and note the use of quotation marks when it says it uses "cron expressions". The cronmaker website states that they use the Quartz cron format, so that is the one I always use.

Answer (score 0):

To answer "For example Trigger starts now or at specified time lets say at 9:15 AM, with interval 5 minutes 2 seconds, then it should trigger 9:20:02, 9:25:02, 9:30:02 (02 is seconds of that minute)"

Create start time at 9:15 and set seconds at 02, see **startTime**, end time is optional based on requirement.

.WithIntervalInMinutes(5) is as usual 5,10,15, N mintues

Finally we can test triggers with **var dt = trigger.GetNextFireTimeUtc();**

---

```
    var dateNow = DateTime.Now;
    var startTime = new DateTime(year: dateNow.Year, month: dateNow.Month, day: dateNow.Day, hour: 9, minute: 15, second: 2);

    var endTime = new DateTime(year: dateNow.Year, month: dateNow.Month, day: dateNow.Day, hour: 15, minute: 19, second: 5);

    Console.WriteLine($"Start time {startTime}");
    Console.WriteLine($"End time {endTime}");

    ITrigger trigger2_every5min_at_2_seconds = TriggerBuilder.Create()
        .WithIdentity("ScrapGoldRateTrigger2", "group123")
        .StartAt(startTime)
        .EndAt(endTime)
        .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
                .RepeatForever()
                .WithIntervalInMinutes(5)
                )
        .Build();

    var dt = trigger.GetNextFireTimeUtc();
    var times = TriggerUtils.ComputeFireTimes(trigger2_every5min_at_2_seconds as IOperableTrigger,
        null, 100);

    foreach (var time in times)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(time.ToLocalTime());
    }
```

---

**Output**
Start time 25-09-2022 09:15:02

End time 25-09-2022 15:19:05

25-09-2022 09:15:02 +05:30

25-09-2022 09:20:02 +05:30

25-09-2022 09:25:02 +05:30

25-09-2022 09:30:02 +05:30

25-09-2022 09:35:02 +05:30

25-09-2022 09:40:02 +05:30

25-09-2022 09:45:02 +05:30

25-09-2022 09:50:02 +05:30

25-09-2022 09:55:02 +05:30

25-09-2022 10:00:02 +05:30

25-09-2022 10:05:02 +05:30

25-09-2022 10:10:02 +05:30

25-09-2022 10:15:02 +05:30

25-09-2022 10:20:02 +05:30

25-09-2022 10:25:02 +05:30

25-09-2022 10:30:02 +05:30